# Close Dialog from Activity open in Child Fragment in NavGraph

Tags: android, navigation, fragment-backstack, android-fragment-manager

I want to close any dialog open from nav_graph on some event.

**NavHostActivity.kt xml**

```
         <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_settings" />
```

**nav_graph_setting.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_settings"
    app:startDestination="@id/settingFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingFragment"
        android:name="matas.matas.settings.fragment.SettingFragment"
        android:label="Min profil”/>
       
</navigation>
```

on Click of a button in **SettingFragment** I call below method

```
private fun highLightMemberCard(view: View) {
        childFragmentManager.let {
            val dialog = MemberCardDialogFragment.getInstance(DisplayUtils.dpToPx(requireContext(),65))
            val ft = it.beginTransaction()
            ft.add(dialog, MemberCardDialogFragment.TAG)
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss()
        }
    }
```

> I simply want to close MemberCardDialogFragment from Activity on certain event?

Comment: you can pass in a callback function from activity to fragment, also add the callback function to the parameter of the fragment. If you have not used callback function then add some more code in your question, from where are you instantiating the SettingsFragment

Comment: from nav_graph_setting

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface

```
interface CallbackFunction{
    fun closeDialog()
}
```

implement that interface in your main activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),CallbackFunction{
    private lateinit var navController: NavController


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

      val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
    .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment

       navController = navHostFragment.navController

   }
    override fun closeDialog() {
          navController.popBackStack()
    }

}
```

Call the function in your fragment as

```
(activity as MainActivity).closeDialog()
```

Comment: Dialog is opening from SettingFragment . I have to send a callback to Fragment not to activity

Comment: you said "I simply want to close MemberCardDialogFragment from Activity on certain event?" eitherwise, you can implement the interface from SettingsFragment and call the method from settingFragment into dialog fragment

Comment: I have to shut a childFragment of my Nav Graph fragment as I was using old navigation graph in my project that doesn't contain <dialog in graph